# Oracle Table Value Merging

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm currently working with Oracle lately and I'm stuck on something.

I have been asked to:
Display the names of those suppliers who have supplied to at least 4 stores.

Here is my query:

```
select SuppCode
from Stocks
group by SuppCode       
having COUNT(DISTINCT StoreCode)>=4
order by SuppCode desc;
```

and I'm getting the correct SuppCode:

```
SUPPCO
------
S3
```

But the SuppName is in another table. How would I change the SuppCode from Stocks, to SuppName from Suppliers, whilst keeping the rest of the query which gives me the correct answer. The only problem is that it's displaying the SuppCode, and not the SuppName which is in Suppliers.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SuppName
from suppliers sp
  join (select SuppCode
        from Stocks
        group by SuppCode       
        having COUNT(DISTINCT StoreCode)>=4
        order by SuppCode desc
  ) st on st.suppCode = sp.suppcode;
```

Comment: Sorted it out nicely, I appreciate your response. Thank you!